# Angular 2 Signature Pad

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to add a signature pad to one of my Angular 4.X application so that I can allow users to sign using touch input. For that I am using the angular2-signature-pad package downloaded from the npm. I want to use the signature pad as one of my form control so that I can get the value of the signature field when the form is submitted (alongwith other form controls of my form). All other fields are working fine but when I am assigning a formcontrol name to signature pad, it throws the following error.

```
No value accessor for form control with name: 'Signature'
```

I have created a plunker for the issue. Please find the link below --
https://plnkr.co/edit/32nEL74I48dDDWermSWQ?p=preview

For easy reference, below is my code for the signature pad for that I have created.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signature-pad';

@Component({
  selector: 'SignatureForm',
  template: `
            <div>  
              <form [formGroup]="signatureForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(signatureForm.value)">
                  <div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="FirstName"/>
                          <small *ngIf="IsValidField('FirstName')" class="text-danger">
                              First Name is required
                          </small>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="LastName"/>
                          <small *ngIf="IsValidField('LastName')" class="text-danger">
                              Last Name is required
                          </small>
                      <signature-pad (onSave)="onSaveHandler($event)" (onClear)="onClearHandler()" [width]="width" [height]="height" [hideFooter]="noFooter" [label]="label" formControlName="Signature"></signature-pad>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              </form>
            </div>
  `,
})
export class SignatureFormComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public signatureForm: FormGroup;
  public width:number = 300;
  public height:number = 300;
  public noFooter:boolean = false;
  public label:string = 'Sign above';
  public formSubmitAttempt:boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.signatureForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        FirstName: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(25)]],
        LastName: ['',[Validators.maxLength(25)]],
        Signature:[null,[Validators.required]]
      });
  }

  public OnSubmit(signatureFormData: any) {
    this.formSubmitAttempt=false;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(signatureFormData));
  }

  onSaveHandler(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  onClearHandler() {
    console.log('On Clear click');
  }

  public IsValidField(field: string,i?:number) {
    return (this.signatureForm.get(field).invalid && this.signatureForm.get(field).touched) || (this.signatureForm.get(field).invalid && this.formSubmitAttempt);
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,SignaturePadModule],
  declarations: [ SignatureFormComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ SignatureFormComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The reason I need it as a form control because I want to save the signature so that when I wish display the form somewhere I shall easily fetch the signature value and assign it back to the formcontrol. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you will have to write the form control component and put the signature pad inside in order for it to take an ngModel or formControlName

Comment: @amit : hey buddy did you found any solution for your question?